# Looking for help with geogebra animation applets

Tags: math-software

I was wondering whether anyone experienced with GeoGebra could create an applet that does this: https://www.geogebra.org/m/jzsxxnhq [image]

but rearranges a cylinder into a cuboid rather than a circle into a rectangle.  I was also wondering whether this applet https://www.geogebra.org/m/yzGzrUxs could be modified or recreated so someone can change the height of the cone.